# Array length in app Android

Tags: android, file

In my app Android I have declared a variable:

> File f = new File(...);
>
> File[] files = f.listFiles();

After, I have to test if there are files in my directory:

> if(**files.length == 0**) { ... }

And here is my problem. This is valid for my smartphone emulator (5.4" Android 4.2.2) and my tablet emulator (10" Android 4.2.2 ), but this is not valid for my emulator 4.0" Android 4.2.2, I have got a mistake and my app is closed, in this case I have to put:

> if(**files == null**) { ... }

How I can fix this for a single expression or to distinguish between the two cases?

Comment: How about `if(files == null || files.length == 0) { ... }`?

Comment: From the doc on `listFiles()`: "Returns:
An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."

Comment: Yes @kamituel I have read this before but, when I obtain files.length = 0 or files = null? My abstract pathname is always a directory ...

Comment: @KryNaC can you explain what "mistake you got" (stacktrace,...)

Answer (score 0):

What about 
`if (files == null || files.length() == 0) {}`
?

Comment: Is it a question, or an answer? :)

Comment: I have already tried this, but this is not valid ... I think just to check and fails

Comment: @KryNaC: I would expect this to work. How are you so sure it doesn't work? Are you sure it this code causing the issue and not something else? If you debug, what is the value of `files` prior to this condition check?

Comment: @KryNaC can you explain what "mistake you got" (stacktrace,...)